# How could I generate this font?

Tags: fonts

I want to use the same font as this paper (title, section, subsection)

https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/306.pdf

I have asked the author, he said they only used \documentclass[letterpaper]{article}.

Does anyone know how to obtain this font?

Thanks.

Comment: Go to your PDF viewer and check the Properties window. All the fonts used are listed, mainly TeX Gyre Termes

Comment: Thank you very much! I have found the answer: Bold Times New Roman